# How to apply splice or any other function to several different arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I'm trying to shorten the following code:

```
    if ( /MATCH/ ){
        splice @identifiers,            $i, 1;
        splice @sequences,              $i, 1;
        splice @optional_informations,  $i, 1;
        splice @quality_scores,         $i, 1;
        splice @barcodes,               $i, 1;
    }
```

Is there a way to iterate over each array and perform splice or any other function?

Comment: Probably, but I think this might be better framed as a wider question - what's your input, and desired output data structures? Because this looks like an `XY problem` to me.

Comment: The real "problem" is that they are using parallel arrays.

Comment: A set of parallel arrays (effectively an HoA) use less memory than an array of objects (AoH), but it's so much harder to work with.

Answer (score 9):

You could iterate over an array of references:

```
@all_arrays = \( # Note the ref-making backslash applied to the list
    @identifiers,
    @sequences,
    @optional_informations,
    @quality_scores,
    @barcodes
);
for $array (@all_arrays)
{
    splice @$array, $i, 1;
}
```

Comment: I learned some Perl today. I didn't think that `\(@foo, @bar, @baz)` would do what it does. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know either. I tried it on a hunch. I can't explain how the operand of the \ doesn't become a flattened list. But it DWIM so hooray

Comment: Perl comes with excellent documentation. One should regularly read everything linked from `perldoc perltoc` at least once a year. See `perldoc perlref`, in "Making References": "*Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using
        square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of
        references!*"

Comment: @DaveCross, Wumpus, was interested too, so looked into it and found this in perlref: "Taking a reference to an enumerated list is...the same as creating a list of references!"  Exclamation point definitely warranted.  Weird inconsistent behavior too as `\(@a)` doesn't behave like `\(@a,@b)`.  Fun stuff.

Comment: To be clear: I didn't expect it to do the same as square brackets. I expected it to flatten all the array elements into a single list and return a list of references to those elements.

Comment: I must have had a distant memory of reading that, which gave me the idea to try it. Still I wouldn't want to try to understand the part of the grammar that actually lets the commas inside the parentheses know that they shouldn't do their usual list-flattening thing because there's a backslash at the next node up the parse tree

Comment: See also [Documentation of backslash operator inducing list context for its operand is missing](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131061)

Comment: Thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 7):

When you find yourself wanting to do similar things to a number of related data structures, that is an indication they should be members of a larger data structure. In this case, you could put all the arrays in a hash:

```
my %dataset = (
    identifiers    => [],
    sequences      => [],
    optional_info  => [],
    quality_scores => [],
    barcodes       => [],
);

if ( /MATCH/ ) {
    splice @$_, $i, 1 for values %dataset;
}
```

In fact, as @ikegami notes in comments, other data structures might be more appropriate depending on the kind of operations you are may carry out. For example, if you ever need to select records using a subset of the values of a variable, say `quality_scores` between 30 and 70, it would be better to store the data as an array of hashes (if the order matters), or as a hash of hashes (if the order does not matter or if you are willing to add an ordinal to the data set.

For example,

```
 my %dataset = (
    id0 => {
        t => '...',
        id => '...',
        sequence => '...',
        optional_info => '...',
        quality_score => '...',
        barcoode => '...',
    },
    # ...
    idn => {
        t => '...',
        id => '...',
        sequence => '...',
        optional_info => '...',
        quality_score => '...',
        barcoode => '...',
    },
 );
```

With that data structure, you can delete a specific record using its identifier (or index if you key on `t`).

Comment: Indeed, this is the nice version you should use when you're willing to refactor the rest of the code using those arrays.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley It would also make it easier to deal with a situation where an additional variable is added to the analysis. Although, I am guessing `@optional_informations` is a catch-all for that kind of stuff, similar to database fields stuffed with comma-separated data etc.

Comment: Probably should be an AoH rather than an HoA. `[ { identifier => $identifier0, sequence => $sequence0, }, { ... }, ... ]`. Or even an HoH so you can "splice" more easily. `{ $identifier0 => { identifier => $identifier0, sequence => $sequence0, }, $identifier1 => { ... }, ... ]`

Comment: @ikegami It really depends. One thing is certain, they should not be stored in individual named arrays.

Comment: Yes, using a HoH makes more sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

we can collectively store references of arrays in an array and iterate through it as below.

```
foreach my $arr_ref (\(@identifiers,@sequences,@optional_informations,@quality_scores)){

     my @tmparr=@{ $arr_ref }[3,4];#slice operation or any other operation can be performed

}
```

Comment: What does this answer add that the other answers do not capture?